# Setting Background shape for tab icon when selected android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, tabs

I am new to `android` and `java`. I am using `tab layout` in my app. It looks like below

[image: My Tab layout]

My Tab layout Code in XML:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:background="#F7F7F7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/tab_text_unselected_color"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/tab_text_selected_color"
        app:tabIndicator="@drawable/custom_tab_indicator"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tab_indicator_color"
        app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText"
        app:tabIconTint="@color/custom_tab_icon_color_setter"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
```

**Drawables:

tab_selector.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/tab_selected_color"
        android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/tab_unselected_color"
        android:state_selected="false"/>
</selector>
```

**custom_tab_indicator.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

**Styles:**

```
<style name="MineCustomTabText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
</style>
```

I want to add a background circle shape to vector icon when selected like the below image.

[image: my required layout]

**Here's the circle shape:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>

</shape>
```

I don't know how to achieve this. Please Help me with some solutions.

I tried modifying this code by adding background to icon.

**custom_tab_icon_color_setter:-**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:background="@drawable/cirle_shape" android:color="@color/tab_icon_selected_color"  android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/tab_icon_unselected_color"/>
</selector>
```

But nothing gets changed. Please help me with some solutions to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Just Add this background to your view

android:background=?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground

No need to create any shape res file. Add this background to the view that u want to show the background.

Comment: Thanks for the response... No changes... it didn't work...